# Python Regex: add restriction that it should NOT be a match if there is a quotation mark somewhere before the match AND somewhere after

Tags: python, regex

I would like to:

1. remove any leading whitespace in the example matches below and
2. exclude matches that have at some position before the string a quotation mark AND at some position after the string another quotation mark (i.e. the strings that should NOT be matched are enclosed by quotation marks but the quotation marks will not necessarily be directly before and after the string).

I tried with combining negative lookbehind & lookahead but I somehow cannot figure it out.

Thank you so much!

My current Python Regex is as follows:

```
r'''(?<=[@])\s*[A-Z0-9.]+(?=\()'''
```

1. @STRING1(         # Result: 'STRING1'        --> works
2. @    STRI..NG2(   # Result: '    STRI..NG2'  --> okay, but excl. whitespace would be preferred
3. @  STRING.3(      # Result: '  STRING.3'       --> okay, but excl. whitespace would be preferred

**Example Text:**
@STRING4("@STRING5( and maybe "another @STRING6("__"maybe here is text") and @STRING7(     " maybe & even another @    STRING8( "  --- "  and a "last"   one   " @STRING9(        &"maybe some more "text"

Right now this returns (including leading whitespaces):

- 'STRING4'
- 'STRING5'
- 'STRING6'
- 'STRING7'
- '    STRING8'
- 'STRING9'

Desired return:

- 'STRING4'
- 'STRING6'
- 'STRING8'

Comment: Your problem description sounds like you should be looking for a proper parser (or perhaps a lexer) instead of a regex.

Comment: STRING6 and STRING8 both have quotation marks before and after them. What you want is more complex than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to it is with the following regex

```
reg = r'(?:\"[^\"]+\")|(?:@\s*([A-Z0-9.]+)\()'
```

You need to then check if the match has a group 1. If it does its a match, otherwise its a false match.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! This looks very promising. I will try to run some tests and give you feedback accordingly. This approach also seems to not need a balanced number of brackets which is nice.

Comment: I tried your solution with several test strings and all of them worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't do everything you want, due to Python not allowing non-fixed width lookbehinds, but this:

```py
reg = r"(?<=@)\s*([A-Z\d.]+)(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*$)"
```

Should work. **NOTE** That it expects the quotes to be properly balanced throughout the string. It also doesn't account for any escaped quotes (`\"`).

Edit: I added a capture group that you can use to remove the leading whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Is there any way to make this not dependent on balanced quotes?

Comment: I don't think so. But you can make sure it is balanced before you use the regex pretty easily. Something like `if teststring.count('"') % 2 == 1: teststring = teststring + '"'`